# What System call creates the parent process?

Tags: linux, kernel

My understanding is that `fork` is the system call that creates a new process by cloning the parent process. By what creates the parent process? If using a C library to create multiple processes, what was the system call to create the first process? For example when running `./main.o`

Comment: Parent process has been created by its parent process and so on until you reach `init` - parent of all processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kernel itself contains an internal call to `execve()` to create process 1 (init), which never exits.

Init() is the root of the whole process tree. It starts off by forking processes for all the known services and other configured tasks, and for all the login devices.

Comment: Ok so in my specific example it would be as Toby says and the shell process would be parent. But, as you go up and up, you eventually reach the parent of everything which is process 1 (init). This process is started with `execve()` system call by the Kernel at boot? Do I have that right?

Comment: @R.Buchanan  I gleaned this information from `https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-3.html#ss3.5` but the text is fairly obscure. `ps -ef` gives the ppid of init as zero. Seems perfectly reasonable for kernel to assert that it is "process zero", and install `init` to be the head of the process tree without a `fork`. `init` must never exit, since its parent is not actually a process.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Nice to see you here, i still recall days discussing over toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your program from a shell, then the shell is its parent process.

The shell calls `fork()` to create a new child process, then in that new process, calls one of the `exec()` family to start running your program.

If your program is started by some other (non-shell) process, the sequence is just the same.

Obviously, this has to start somewhere: the ultimate ancestor of all processes is the `init` process (PID 0), which is started magically by the kernel to get userspace started.